# needs reloading the page for different button action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two textarea. One for converting English to Arabic and another for arabic to english.

There are two different buttons for both of this action. And I am using same textareas for vise versa action.

If I perform Enlish to Ar convertion first then it does not allow me Ar to En without page loading.

What is the issue here.

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
                    <a id="Bar2en" rel="leanModal" name="ar2en" href="#ar2en" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Arabic to English</a>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <a id="Ben2ar" rel="leanModal" name="ben2ara" href="#ar2en"  class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">English to Arabic</a>
                    </div>

<div id="ar2en">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    Arabic : 
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    <textarea style="height:200px" id="arabic" name = "arabic" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>                            
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success" id="ar2eng" href=""> Ar to En </a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    English : 
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    <textarea style="height:200px" name = "english"  id="english" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>                            
                    <label id="engL">Enter text in the box</label>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">                           
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>       
    </div>
     </div>    
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $( "#ar2en" ).click(function() {
            var arabic = document.getElementById("arabic").value;
            //alert (arabic)
            ar2en(arabic);
            return false;
            });

        function ar2en(arabic)
        {               
            var xmlhttp;
            english.innerHTML = '';
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }           
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                //document.getElementById("old-records").innerHTML = "";                
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var div2 = document.getElementById("english");
                                div2.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","processAra.php");              
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send('arabic=' + arabic + '&type=' + 'ar' ) ;           
            //alert(arabic);
        }               
// -----------
    $( "#english" ).keyup(function() {
            //var cat = $("#cats option:selected").html();
//          alert(test);
            var english = document.getElementById("english").value;
            //alert (arabic)
            en2ar(english);
            return false;
            });
        function en2ar(english)
        {               
            var xmlhttp;
            arabic.innerHTML = '';
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }           
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                //document.getElementById("old-records").innerHTML = "";                
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var div2 = document.getElementById("arabic");
                                div2.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","processAra.php");              
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send('arabic=' + english + '&type=' + 'en' ) ;          
            //alert(arabic);
        }   
        $("#Ben2ar")
        .click(
            //location.reload(true);
             function ()
             {
             $("#ar2eng").hide();
             $("#engL").show();
            return;
             }
        );
        $("#Bar2en")
        .click(
            //location.reload(true);
             function ()
             {
             $("#ar2eng").show();
             $("#engL").hide();
            return;
             }
        );
```

Comment: in short u want to do is Arabic=>English without page load .correct?

Comment: please tell ur problem by refering fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/76ym4/

Comment: @PratikJoshi: there needs multiple php source files to be included, so I could not put on fidle

Comment: Then how do i test which part is not working :) ?

Comment: Why dont u use $.ajax ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi: I tried but i was facing issue. So shifted to ajax

Comment: Then how do i test which part is not working :) ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi: there is some logical error in js/html. I thought someone may catch. I am using `english.innerHTML = '';` to clear before reuse. Is there any issue with it?

Comment: Dude,             var english = document.getElementById("english").value; Here This var english variable is defined as local variable in your code in function .And it is  getting accessed in ar2en(arabic) function .You should define it globally above all js lines. what is console error?

Comment: @PratikJoshi: no error in console

Comment: Tried it but no help yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56870/discussion-between-user3449212-and-pratik-joshi).